# Como concatenar dados iguais de uma coluna em linhas no Python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Base de Dados]

O que eu preciso é encontrar uma função no Python que monte meu arquivo dessa forma. Já pesquisei no pandas e não achei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira é fazer:

```
df.groupby('Categoria').agg({'Descricao':lambda col: ', '.join(col)}).reset_index()
```

Dessa maneira você está agrupando os dados iguais da coluna `Categoria` e usando para a coluna `Descricao` a regra `lambda col: ', '.join(col)`, ou seja, concatenando os dados em uma string separado por `', '`.

Comment: Muito obrigada Alex ! Resolveu :)